# What is my mechanic doing when he says he tunes the engine on the annual service?

Tags: motorcycle, throttle, service

Whenever I take my motorcycle (MT-07/FZ-07) to the mechanic for the annual service the mechanic says he "tunes" the engine. I do feel a difference, especially a much smoother throttle response, and I was wondering what could he be doing to the engine.

According to the service manual the annual service should include the throttle body synchronization. Does that explain it or is there some electronic magic going on with the fuel injection or something?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't ask him?

Comment: He wouldn't answer. Trade secret sort of thing. It's strange he makes such a secret of it. Which made me even more curious.

Comment: Might consider finding new mechanic? Edit: tune is nebulous. It can mean different things to different people.

Comment: But what could he be doing that would do such an improvement on throttle response? This is just an annual service so I'm sure he's not going in too deep. Could throttle body synchronization explain it?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with bikes but cleaning throttle body/MAF can definitely help performance in cars.

Comment: There is no "trade secret" here.  The MT-07/FZ-07 has a Factory Service Manual that details all the periodic maintenance procedures needed as well as how to do them.  The needed procedures are also likely included in your Owners Manual.  Oh, and find another mechanic!

Comment: There's an excellent auto repair shop on YouTube showing every technical detail of a repair. Apparently this mechanic is confident in his abilities to share his thoughts and expertise to anyone willing to watch and learn without losing any secrets to expertise he's not afraid of sharing. As mentioned, there aren't any secrets of motorcycle maintenance with the exception of those afraid of revealing their inabilities. Knowledgeable people share knowledge.

Comment: @FDryer what is that youtube channel you mentioned?

Comment: South Main Auto